# Live Server - A network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: connection-string

My site's login / membership doesn't work on the live server, when hosted. I get this infamous error:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

My connection string is as follows:

```
<add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

you need check [TCP/IP properties](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/ea9f0e79-ef69-4d47-9862-d53a1e460003)
 in sql server configuration